Are my skin colors realistic?
I want to make sure that my human skin colors are realistic and make sense. I've tried to find a balance between aligning them with latitude and climate, and allowing for randomness caused by migration. I've included maps of the biomes and climate. Are my skin colors realistic?




You're building a fictional world. By definition it isn't real. Do you believe there is some definitive formula to calculate skin color in a region? Because if there isn't you're kind of just asking for a vibes check from us which is entirely opinion based.

@sphennings Something not being perfectly formulaic doesn't mean it's some random magic with nothing to say about it

@IchthysKing Exactly! Just because the world is fictional doesn't mean I want to just throw darts at the wall. I'm trying to build realistically. That's what this site is for.

In reality human skin pigmentation varies clinally and there are only a handful of places with sharp boundaries.

just fyi your really square ice sheet line in the north looks very unnatural for an earth like world

Don't worry about the ice sheet, the squareish line is caused by the tidal heating of a gas giant, but it's nothing compared to the sun.

What's the atmosphere like? More importantly, what's the UV like?

@IchthysKing you're not wrong but to ask a question on this site is to play by our rules which place restrictions on the form questions can take. Questions that are primarily based in opinion are not permitted here.

more or less accurate. The only change I would make is to give people who live in hot and arid climate darker skin, because they whole point of dark skin is to protect from UV, which is impossible to avoid if you live on some kind of a savannah or a desert. In the tropical jungle, you can avoid UV just fine, so the skin color does not need to be as dark.

@sphennings Commenting a rule under a question doesn't make the question violate said rule

It would be kind of fun to switch it and have the switch as a point of conflict, if the world is a far-future Earthling colony. "Swap regions with us, we're obviously phenotypically suited for your kind of region and you for ours!" "No, this is our homeland, given to us by the sacred people of Landing Site, where our prophets are buried! Get your own!"

Yes, it is more than adequate.
It broadly matches UV levels, the primary driver of human skin color, which is more than enough for this to be realistic. But it takes thousands of years for skin color to adapt to the local UV levels, which means migration easily overrides UV levels, so any irregularities can easily be dismissed as migration patterns from the past.
For comparison on earth the match between UV and skin darkness is good for broad strokes at best, largely because of the constant migration.


Why does your map show Australians having very dark skin? Are they not mostly of British descent and therefore fairly white?

@Michael Could be accounting for the indigenous population only? Aboriginal people have very dark skin. Kind of weird considering the note about South America though.

@Michael MKHC is correct it is a map of the indiginous population, aka prior to the the rapid migration created by modern technology. in enough time expect it to return to that dark skinned state, in the same way the dark skinned people who populated the british islands became light skinned. south america was only populated fairly recently in evolutionary terms, and by a group that was very light skinned, it is slightly easier to go from pale to dark than pale to dark, the former only reguires the loss of gene expression.

@John You say "pale to dark" twice.  Can you clarify which should be "dark to pale"?

Oh yeah that should be dark to pale is easier than pale to dark, too bad I can't edit comments.

@John You could just copy/delete/paste/edit, if you don't mind the later timestamp for your comment. I do that occasionally, and here it won't make your comment appear after any significant replies to your original comment.

It depends on your migration pattern
Making melanin is hard.  There's a special structure, the melanosome, which has to be transferred from the cell that makes it (the melanocyte) to the other cells (keratinocytes).  There's a special chemical pathway to deposit the pigment in that structure.  The pathway is present in our world's humans because they emerged from a long line of ancestors, all living at low latitudes with substantial sun exposure.  So the map you drew probably only works if the humans happened to start in the darker area.
That said, your other aberrations from a simple latitude dependence are excusable.  After all, equatorial Americans never regained full pigmentation.  If you need another explanation besides it being hard to revert genetically, you could postulate the presence of vitamin D rich food resources, such as a fish or fungus, which is a staple diet in the region.
That said... dang... it's a fictional world.  Do they really have to be dull old humans?  No iridescence, no bioluminescence, no chromatophores, nothing...?

Can you explain further? I'm not sure I understand. Why wouldn't humans develop dark skin at the equator, even if they started somewhere else? I mean, humans started in Africa and yet you see light skin in Europe...

@J.Rubio Having skin high in melanin reduces the production of vitamin D from UV.  Having dark skin in a low-UV latitude could lead to vitamin deficiencies... especially with warm clothing.

Okay, but I don't have any dark skin in low UV latitudes.

@J.Rubio I think the point Mike is making is that skin pigmentation took a long time to evolve. Switching it off on the other hand is fairly quick. Humans only left Africa 60,000 years ago; that's not very long evolutionarily. Long enough for minor tweaks but not enough for major changes

With enough migration, connection, and colonialism you could get away with murder on this
Skin pigmentation on humans roughly corresponds to exposure to the sun, but it takes a VERY long time to adapt. Cultural migration and adaptation moves orders of magnitude faster. A whole group of people can move into an area and become a long-standing ethnicity in a short enough time that they don't adapt their skin and hair color.  Look up the Berber people as an extreme case of this: they've been there since literally ancient history and they're still very fair.
So, if there's parts of the world that only got inhabited recently enough to not have a fossil record they are going to have a skin color more associated with where their ancestors came from instead of where they are.

Modern Australians are another great example. They pay for it with high skin cancer rates.

You should start by specifying what role the coloration plays in the people's development. Melanin is something that prevents damage from UV radiation, but can result in vitamin D deficiency if taken too far. Our skin color is one of the traits that isn't tightly bound into our genetics, requiring less change than something like the number of toes. The end result is that, for any latitude, there is an optimal balance that natural selection will trend towards.
For you, what do the colors represent? It looks like blue might provide a degree of heat resistance, and that purple acts to store heat in cold weather. You might have a skin tone that provides better symbiosis with some plant that only grows in specific biomes. The coloration might be due to a form of waterproofing in a rain forest, or for moisture retention in the desert.
Although latitude is the key characteristic that determines human skin color, there are other things, like hair and eye color, that primarily diffuse in from specific parts of the world. Your skin colors might be like that.
Really, you can have skin color be anything you want it to be, as long as you have some kind of vague explanation. You probably also want to figure out what happens during cross-breeding, or why cross-breeding doesn't happen.

Just a note, there aren't any purple or blue skin colors on this map. Those are the climate and biome maps, with keys on the side. Only the first map is of skin colors.

@J.Rubio, Ah, thanks, I misread it. In that case, John's answer is more than adequate. You'll still face migrational diffusion, though.
